Overlapping header on image
I am trying to overlaap the header and the image i cant get it to working
I tried using everything in 1 div and use position relative to make them overlaap but it didnt work
and i tried also use z index but still it aint working
here is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Pixelcyber</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="home.html" style="text-decoration:none">Home</a>
            <a href="portfolio.html" style="text-decoration:none">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="projects.html" style="text-decoration:none">Projects</a>
            <a href="contacts.html" style="text-decoration:none">Contacts</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <h1>Coder</h1>
    <p>4 years experience</p>
    <div class="wp">
        <img src="luffy.png" alt="luffy">
    </div>
</body>
</html>


Please revise the code to create an actual [mre]

Also, please explain which header do you want overlapping with the image. Do you want the entire header div to overlap or just some specific element?

@AniketPandey the div header is a block and i want the header be at top overlapping everything but the picture has a problem because it is under the header and i yet couldn't get it to  be like a wallpaper

Have you even tried positioning it?? I don't see any css in your code.. Please give proper details and code in the question

@AniketPandey thanks for your help but another guy helped me with the css apreceate your help

you can do it with
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;

as in here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rtpd4i?file=index.html
